# Installing Packages on Mac OS

Tags: packages, installing, mac

I am using Texmaker with MacTex v2013 on OS X Mavericks 10.9.

I want to install some packages that don't come by default with MacTeX (e.g. `wrapfig.sty`). One way to do this would be download the `.sty` files and place them in the current working directory (cwd), but since I have a lot of packages to download, this might take a long time. Alternatively, I tried using the TeX Live Utility application, and going to packages, selecting all and then install, but unfortunately TeX Live Utility just sits there doing nothing, is there any way that I can download and install all the TeX packages that I am missing?

Comment: If you have installed MacTeX (not BasicTeX) then you *definitely* have `wrapfig.sty`, and in fact almost everything on CTAN except for the most obscure things.  So either you haven't actually installed MacTeX or you're doing something else wrong. How do you know `wrapfig` is not installed?

Comment: A tex file showed the"couldnt find wrapfig.sty" error. Also in TexLive, wrapfig.sty shows "not installed."

Comment: So maybe you installed BasicTeX instead?  Do you still have the MacTeX.pkg that you installed from?  It should be about 2.36 Gb.  Really the simplest way to solve this problem is to reinstall MacTeX, I think.

Comment: OK, Thank you for the advice. unfortunately I dont have the .pkg file. I will download MacTEX again, and see what happens.

Comment: Other than that - Isnt there any option to just install all the package files?

Comment: In principle, assuming you installed BasicTeX and everything is set up correctly, you can install things using the TeX Live utility, but the simplest solution by far is to use the MacTeX installer itself.  The you just need to use TeX Live utility occasionally to update to the latest versions of the packages.  Also, to be completely up to date,  you'll need to reinstall Mac TeX on a yearly basis (when the new TeX Live is produced) since you can't currently update from one year to the next.

Comment: Thanks for your help Alan. I tried installing the packages with TexLive and this time it worked - mustve been an issue with the servers or something. All the packages now show "installed." :).

Comment: Ok.  I'll turn my comments into some kind of answer so that this question doesn't remain without any answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The MacTeX distribution is a full TeX Live distribution, and as such should contain almost any package you are likely to use (essentially everything in CTAN that has a verified free licence.)

However, it's possible that when you first installed MacTeX you chose to install the small version called BasicTeX, which does not install everything.

In principle, with BasicTeX you can use the TeX Live Utility to install all of the other packages. If this is not working, it's possible that you are simply having trouble reaching the appropriate servers, in which case, trying again might solve the problem.

Alternatively, you can just reinstall the full MacTeX, which in most cases is likely to be the easiest (and ultimately fastest) solution if you have access to a fast internet connection.

Answer (score -1):

You can see this answer

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1390828/how-do-i-install-a-latex-sty-file-on-osx

and You can do in the /usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/.

I suggest you install the full package

Comment: Welcome to Tex.SX!  Generally we discourage link only answers, trying to keep this site self contained.  Short remarks with links are better suited as comments.  In this case, the answers you link to are quite old, and certainly predate Mavericks, though much of what is said there is still relevant.