# A lite install for Mac OS X

Tags: installing, mac

The full MacTex install is 2.5GB, which is penal for any sporadic user. Can someone talk me through a lite install, i.e. BasicTex plus how to supplement it with one or two packages (e.g."accents.sty"), so I can contribute to a one-off .tex collaboration. Anything else that may be useful, fundamental, or necessary?

Comment: Not already covered in [an earlier Q&A](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/149550/46980)?

Comment: We can't possibly know what your collaborators use. You need to ask them which packages you need. But bear in mind that they may tell you you need package X and you may install package X but still be unable to use package X because package X requires packages Y, Z and H, which you don't have. Especially if you don't know TeX well, you are likely to find the experience extremely frustrating. Either install MacTeX or use one of the online options. You will avoid a world of pain.

Comment: The question linked by @Davïd mentions BasicTeX, and I think you could probably get away with installing that and using [TeX Live Utility](http://amaxwell.github.io/tlutility/) for package/style file management. I'm not sure if TL Util is included in BasicTeX, but you can download the standalone app at the homepage listed above.

Comment: We may know what packages required because they're listed in the errors at Typesetting. A useful answer will detail how when given a few missing packages (& perhaps other very common errors) a newbie can edit and typeset a PDF. The linked answer says " in principle.. use TeX Live Utility to install all of the other packages. If this is not working, it's possible that you are simply having trouble reaching the appropriate servers, in which case, try again". I'm hoping for a less principle and more detail or walk-thru answer; both TexShop and TL Util must point to same folder etc. Tks